# stock data to fit for Conv2D - Python tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to feed stock data to Conv2D. But ran into dimension problem. I have no idea how to solve it and need help. Below are detailed steps that I have implemented.

**I have attached data and code in the following link:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1snsQ-96AeRn521oc0aQVlTTd9nHbtyjO?usp=sharing

by the code itself should run. It will download the data automatically. but ive taken out the featuers to simplify the run. So it will have 5 features in the attached code.

but to give you quick glance of
**The Problem I had**-----------------------

**1. Got stock data and generated some features, it looks like:**
[image]

**2. Add time step to it by using:**

def reshape_data(X, y, period=28):

```
n_past = period # number of days to look back in the past and compile into a time series
trainX = []
trainY = np.array(y.iloc[n_past:])
trainY = trainY[..., np.newaxis]
for i in range(n_past, len(X)):
    trainX.append(X[i - n_past:i, 0:X.shape[1]])
trainX = np.array(trainX)
return trainX, trainY
```

[image]

Note:

**data can be found here**

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1snsQ-96AeRn521oc0aQVlTTd9nHbtyjO?usp=sharing

I have applied pca on it. But simply convert it into numpy and apply reshap_data() on trainX should work

```
trainX, trainY = reshape_data(X_train_pca, y_train, period=30)
```

**3. shape**

```
trainX (5768, 30, 30) # 5768-rows, 30- time steps, 30- # of features

trainY (5768,1)
```

**4. Add 1 axis after train X**

```
trainX = trainX[...,np.newaxis]

trainX is now (5768, 30, 30, 1)
```

**5. Build model**

[image]

**6. fit and run**

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01) , metrics="mse", loss='binary_crossentropy')

reduce_lr  = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',factor=0.5,patience=10,verbose=0,mode='auto',min_delta=0.0002,cooldown=0,min_lr=0.0001)


early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=80, mode="min",  restore_best_weights = True)

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=300,
               batch_size= 512, shuffle=False, verbose = 1,
               # validation_data=(testX, testY),
               validation_split=0.2,
               callbacks=[early_stop, reduce_lr] )
```

**7. ERROR**

[image]

I thought since I have convered the stock into 30,30,1 should looks like a image dataset, which would enable tensorflow to work. But somehow it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two layers after your convolution layer:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

And do not mix up `tensorflow.keras` and `keras`. Rather just use `tensorflow.keras` for everything.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: still the same error message

Comment: Na, I just ran your code with the changes I suggested. Check the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WzGxKoaBN_gNvblbGCj1QnvZJO5Iqlhk?usp=sharing <-- it is running just fine ;) @George

Comment: you are right! I think it must be something with the setting that I enabled GPU! Thanks a lot!